# I get a blank JFrame when i call my the JFrame subclass from the main method. How can I fix?

Tags: java

This is my frame class. I am trying to call this class from my main method but i only get a blank frame, instead of displaying my 400x400 frame, panel, and button.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {


    public void getFrame() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        JButton button= new JButton();
        button= new JButton("Click");
        panel.add(button);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This is my main method

```
public class Test extends JFrame  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame f= new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: you never call the `getFrame()`method. Plus this method behaviour is weird as it's an instance method that creates a new instance but never returns or display it. Maybe your intention was to do this panel/button creation inside the `Frame`constructor?

Comment: this was so helpful. I'll remind myself to never do that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has ***two*** JFrames, not one. One is the Frame class itself which extends JFrame, and which your displaying. But it holds no components, and so you are seeing nothing but a blank window, as expected.

The other JFrame is created in the `getFrame()` method, a method that you never call in your main method.

Suggestion: do not have Frame extend JFrame, but instead create your Frame instance in the main method and then call the `getFrame()` method on it to display the JFrame that has components within it.

Comment: @default Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating an instance of your Frame class, which calls the default constructor Frame(), which has nothing in it so your getFrame() method never runs. The reason you're seeing a blank JFrame is that your Frame class extends JFrame so it is infact a JFrame itself, which you've set visible.